# How can I use functions like NUMBERVALUE() across a whole column/range in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of data that I want to get the average of. (F column below, GREEN)
Unfortunetely, each cell has the unit in it, thus I cannot simply use AVERAGE().

Before I continue, please note that I'm *not* asking for a better way of removing the units (That's a different question.)

Also note that in my included image, just below each formula is the formula in text.

My first attempt at getting the average was to make another column next to it using `=LEFT(F,3)` (Column L, RED) however trying to take the average of that failed (Column N, PINK), presumably because the result was a text string.

So I then tried using wrapping `LEFT()` in `NUMBERVALUE()`, giving me `=AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(L17:L36))` but that just returns the that row's value (Column N, PURPLE)

Next I tried using doing the whole thing at once using `=AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(G17:G36,3)))` (Column N, GREY) but that obviously wasn't going to work either.

Finally, I made a column using `=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(F36,3))` (Column G, BLUE) and then taking the `AVERAGE()` of that (Column I, GOLD).

That worked, but **how can I use `NUMBERVALUE()` and `LEFT()` for a whole column?**
I want something like `=AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(G17:G36,3)))` to work.

[image: Example Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you suggested, entered as an **Array Formula** will work

```
=AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(G17:G36,3)))
```

completed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: I cant seem to get `numbervalue` to work but it did with `int` ie. `=AVERAGE(INT(LEFT(F17:F36,3)))` also completed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: @user3240704 tested and working for me on Excel 2013

Comment: That worked for me in Excel 2016, and I didn't use INT(). Your answer was 3 minutes before zgirod's, so I may give you the accept.

Comment: @chrisneilsen @Bort my apologies, `NUMBERVALUE` was introduced in [2013/Mac2011](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NUMBERVALUE-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879) & I'm on 2007. `INT` will work for backwards compatibility :)

Answer (score 3):

Your formula of `=AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(G17:G36,3)))` is actually correct.  However you are missing one step, you need to convert it to an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7).  After entering in the formula you need to make sure you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to tell excel you want to do an array formula or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on a Mac.

That should do it for you.

Comment: Your answer is correct, however it looks like chris neilsen beat you by 3 minutes, though yours is ever-so-slightly more thorough. Tough call.

Comment: Haha.  No worries.  Early bird gets the worm.  Give it to Chris.